# colorlettrine only support a few characters

Tags: color, lettrine, ebgaramond

I am trying to use colorlettrine package. I installed EB Garamond package, but soon discovered that only a few letter are supported. If I try S for example, it comes up as an empty box.

Are there some alternatives that I could try to achieve similar effect?

Does anyone know what work I could do to add more characters?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... It is too difficult to give suggestion without seeing your codes? Can you provide a `MWE`, what you tried so far?

Comment: EB Garamond was simply lacking many of the initials. However, missing initials were recently added, and the latin alphabet in now complete! (See [here](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/tree/master/SFD/EBGaramond-Initials.sfdir).) So if you download the EB Garamond font from github and use that with coloredlettrine, it should work now (I did not test it, though).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE. `coloredlettrine` is distinct because each glyph consists of two parts: a front (the letter) and a back (the embellishment). This creates the opportunity to have the letter coloured in a way that is distinct from the embellishment. However, as you discovered, only a few letters are available: A, F, G, L, N, O, Q and T.

There are quite a few fonts with decorative initials that can be used to produce lettrines. See the [TUG font catalogue](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/otherfonts.html#initials). I used the `GoudyIn` package to access the Goudy Initialen font.

The `lettrine` package also provides the option of using a graphic as a lettrine. I use this method with some decorative letters I picked up somewhere on the web. I regret that I did not note the source.

[image]

```
% Compile with xelatex or lualatex
% The two EB Garamond Initials fonts must be installed to use \coloredlettrine.
% Graphics with the file names m.jpg, n.jpg and o.jpg, or any 
% other graphic file format must be available to use \lettrine[image...
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine; also on CTAN
\usepackage{coloredlettrine} %loads [svgnames]{xcolor} and {lettrine}
% Requires 2 fonts:
% EB Garamond Initials Fill1 Regular
% EB Garamond Initials Fill2 Regular
\setmainfont[RawFeature={+ss02,+cv01,+ss05,+dlig},
             ItalicFeatures={RawFeature=+cv04}]{EB Garamond}
\renewcommand{\EBLettrineBackColor}{NavyBlue}
\renewcommand{\EBLettrineFrontColor}{Maroon}

\usepackage{lettrine} 
\usepackage{GoudyIn}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\color{Maroon}\GoudyInfamily{}}%
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}
\newcommand*{\mylettrine}[1]{\lettrine[lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}}

\begin{document}

\coloredlettrine[lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{A}{apt}\linebreak
\coloredlettrine[lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{G}{apt}\linebreak
\coloredlettrine[lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{T}{apt}\linebreak

\renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\color{Maroon}\GoudyInfamily{}}%
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}

\mylettrine{A}{apt}
\mylettrine{B}{apt}
\mylettrine{C}{apt}

\lettrine[image,lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{M}{apt}
\lettrine[image,lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{N}{apt}
\lettrine[image,lines=1,realheight=false,findent=3pt,nindent=0pt]{O}{apt}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful! So with the TUG fonts I can still adjust the color of the overall letter, I just can't have two colors?