# Current Status of the Remaining Garamond Initials to be Colorized (Colorlettrine Package)

Tags: color, lettrine, ebgaramond, drop-cap, garamond

Ten years ago today, the following was posted on Tex Talk:

https://tex-talk.net/2011/08/putting-colors-in-initials/

However, it seems that no new dropcaps have been added over the past ten years, as indicated, for example, by last year's post [colorlettrine only support a few characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563954/colorlettrine-only-support-a-few-characters/563970#563970)

It appears to me, although I might be wrong, that only the initials T, A, and G have been colorized.

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Does anyone know what the current status of the missing colorized Garamond initials is?

Thank you.

Comment: since you are basically asking about one person's project contacting via a github issue in the project probably better than asking here

Comment: @David Carlisle Thank you for your comment. I have removed the part of the question which asked if the individual has abandoned the proposed project.

Comment: @David Carlisle I hope the question  as it stands now is appropriate as it pertains to a package readily available to LaTeX users which is admittedly a work-in-progress; but after ten years, I thought it OK to ask if we should still expect the additions.

Comment: well it still seems better to ask the maintainer, no one else can really tell you about the status (other than the data you already know such as the commit history on the project)

Comment: @David Carlisle I have just sent R. Pinson an email inquiring as to the current status of the initials and provided a link to this question. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [commit](https://github.com/raphink/coloredlettrine/commits?author=raphink) activity, it appears that Rafael has not done any substantive work since originally starting the project. The most recent update, adding `FUNDING.yml` appears to be something that he applied to all his repositories at the same time, so I would assume it's something that is, if not formally abandoned, is functionally so. You could always reach out to him directly. He has contact info at [his website](https://raphink.info).

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this helpful information.